# Это бессоюзное СП?

Tags: пунктуация

Пара отправилась в Италию на медовый месяц, путешествовать по средиземному морю на яхте.

Answer (score 3):

***Пара отправилась в Италию на медовый месяц, путешествовать по Средиземному морю на яхте.***

Это простое предложение с авторским обособлением.

Сравнить: *Пара отправилась путешествовать по Средиземному морю на яхте* (вариант без обособления).

Обособленный оборот на основе инфинитива является **обстоятельством цели** (отправилась зачем), в данном случае он обособлен в распространенном предложении **со значением уточнения.**

Comment: *Пара отправилась в Италию на медовый месяц, чтобы путешествовать по Средиземному морю на яхте.* - А так уже не простое предложение. Мне кажется, что здесь не всё так однозначно.

Comment: Есть такое понятие, как синтаксическая синонимия. Это когда одно и тоже содержание можно выразить разными грамматическими формами. Например, обстоятельственный оборот можно обособить, можно не обособлять,  можно заменить СПП, БСП и т.д.  Но вот при анализе этих грамматических форм их мешать между собой не надо, каждой форме - свой анализ.